# Carmicheal numbers are square free

Tags: number-theory, carmichael-numbers

[Carmichael number square free](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764812/carmichael-number-square-free)

I was reading this question.can some one explain how to arrive from here In **particular, $a^{n−1} \equiv 1\pmod{p^t}$**, to here $a^n \equiv a\pmod{p^2}$.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by $a$, then note that if $p^t | n$ where $t \geq 2$, then certainly $p^2 | n$.

So $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {p^t} \implies a^n \equiv a \pmod {p^t} \implies a^n \equiv a \pmod {p^2}$ since $t \geq 2$.

Comment: sorry I have just started number theory could you please explain how did you  arrive at $a^{n} \equiv a (mod p^2)$ from $(mod p^t)$.I mean how did you reduce from $mod p^t$ to $mod p^2$

Comment: @viru Just write down what it means: $a^n \equiv a \pmod {p^t} \iff a^n - a \equiv 0 \pmod {p^t} \iff p^t | \left(a^n - a\right) \iff a^n - a = p^tb$ (some $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ $\iff a^n - a = p^2 \cdot \left(p^{t-2} b\right) \implies p^2 | \left(a^n - a\right) \iff a^n - a \equiv 0 \pmod {p^2} \iff a^n \equiv a \pmod {p^2}$

Comment: Thank you for you patience .Should have done it myself.Got it :)

Comment: If $\alpha$ is divisble by $\beta^n$, then it is also divisible by any $\beta^m$ with $m \geq n$. You can view this as a consequence of the transitive property of divisibility.

Comment: @viru No problem! Good luck with your studies in number theory, hope you enjoy it as much as I do!

Comment: @viru One more thing: to format mod notation, you should use "pmod" (with the backslash). This fills in the brackets for you as well as making it look right, so you just need to put pmod and then the modulus you're working over (in curly brackets if it's more than one character, has a power etc.).

Comment: Got it.will use that next time :)